# rails 3.2 scope combination with impressionist gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have impressionist gem in my rails application and i want to create a scope to return the most viewed item, by adding `is_impressionable` to the model i am able to return the view counts (as in number of views) on the resource using `object.impressionist_count` method but i dont know how to create a scope in my model for most viewed object. the table name created by `impressionist gem` is `impressions`
Your help will be very much appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model, for example CustomImpression and set the table:

```
class CustomImpression < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'impressions'

  belongs_to :user

  scope :my_custom_scope, ...

  def my_custom_function 
    ...
  end
end
```